# Check the convergence of $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{(x-a)^n}$ for different values of $n$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I was solving the problem by taking two cases i.e. for $n=1$ and $n \neq 1$ and reached to the point
$$ \lim_{l \rightarrow a^{+}}\left\{\frac{1}{1-n} \left[ \frac{1}{(b-a)^{n-1}}-
\frac{1}{(l-a)^{n-1}} \right] ,n \neq 1 \right. $$
After which according to me for n>1 the limit tends to $\infty$ and hence, integral diverges and for n<1 the limit tends to $\frac{1}{1-n} \left[ \frac{1}{(b-a)^{n-1}}\right]$
however the answer says the opposite for the values of n.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do i check the convergence of $\int^{b}_{a}\frac{dx}{(x-a)^p}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415486/how-do-i-check-the-convergence-of-intb-a-fracdxx-ap) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7Ba%7D%5E%7Bb%7D%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B(x-a)%5En%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aconvergence&p=1). Note the answer there basically agrees with yours, and I also agree, so your other answer is likely incorrect. Using $t=x-a$, the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{b-a}\frac{dt}{t^{n}}=\int_{0}^{b-a}t^{-n}dt$. ...

Comment: (cont.) For $n=1$, we get $\ln(t)\rvert_{0}^{b-a}=\infty$, while for $n\neq 1$ gives $\left.\frac{t^{-n+1}}{-n+1}\right\rvert_{0}^{b-a}$ which, for $n\gt 1$, is $\infty$, while for $n\lt 1$, it's $\frac{(b-a)^{1-n}}{(1-n)}$, as you basically stated. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.